# Ensuring a size is a factor of the screen size

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I have a GridView in Android which objects change size during a screen rotation. I also want there to be no gaps in between the objects. I want each View to be around 150-200dp.

At first, I was thinking that I could just get the total screen width (`int totalWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();`) and use something like `m_IconSize = Math.min(totalWidth / 4, 175);` to get the max icon size, then set the grid view's columns with `gridView.setNumColumns(totalWidth / m_IconSize);`.

However, for high density resolutions or in the horizontal orientation, it'll always default to the 175, which isn't a factor of the width, and it'll have gaps in between each object in the GridView. How can I make it gapless?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm It's kind of obvious that in landscape it will be greater than 175 (any screen that has more than 700 pixels will do it), so the 175 will be applied. In a more general note, you should never use fixed pixel sizes, create an entry in your dimens.xml and then read it `int pixels = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.whatever);`, but that will only adjust for density, not for horizontal space.

Sounds like you should instead try to find the maximum number of icons you can fit at an approximate size and then use that size, instead of always trying to use 4.